# Javascript output incorrect

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```js
var form = document.getElementById("addStudent");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  // Get form items
  var jerseyNumber = document.getElementById("jerseyNumber").value;
  var completions = document.getElementById("completions").value;
  var attempts = document.getElementById("attempts").value;
  var player = new Object();
  player.attempts = attempts;
  player.completions = completions;
  player.jerseyNumber = jerseyNumber;

  function percentage() {
    var e = ((player.completions / player.attempts) * 100);
    return e;
  }

  function showResults(event) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Freethrow Percentage for # " + player.jerseyNumber + " is " + percentage.e + "%";
  }
  showResults();
  resetForm(jerseyNumber, completions, attempts);
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting
}, false);

// Resets the form after it's submitted
function resetForm(jerseyNumber, freethrowCompleted, freethrowAttempts) {
  jerseyNumber.value = "";
  freethrowCompleted.value = "";
  freethrowAttempts.value = "";
}
```

and the output is
"Freethrow Percentage for # 23 is undefined%"

and basically I have no idea why `e` is returning as `undefined`.

And this is what im trying to do

1. After the form is submitted, your program must create a JavaScript object to represent the player.  The object must have properties to contain their jersey number, their shooting attempts, and shooting completions.  The object must also contain a method that calculates the players free throw shooting percentage. Here's the formula: Math.round(completed / attempts * 100)
2. You must then create a function called showResults() that takes this student object as an argument and displays the results on the screen in the div with id="results".  The example below uses this HTML: `<h4>Freethrow Percentage for #23: 94%</h4>`.  The shooting percentage must be rounded to the nearest whole number (see formula above and screenshot below) with a percent symbol.

Comment: You are writing out `percentage.e`, but there is no value assigned to that. *e* is a variable, not an object property. Variables are not available as properties of functions, you want `... + percentage() + ...`.

Comment: To call a function you put parentheses after it, `percentage()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `percentage()`, calling your percentage method, not trying to reference the property `e` on the percentage object.

Comment: No `.e` after the function.

Comment: Doh! Thanks :) overlooked

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Freethrow Percentage for # " + player.jerseyNumber + " is " + percentage.e + "%";
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Freethrow Percentage for # " + player.jerseyNumber + " is " + percentage() + "%";
```

`percentage` is the name of a function, not an object. To call a function you put parentheses after it. `e` is the name of the local variable that it returns, not a property.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your function isn't part of your object. Try including the `percentage` function in the object like this.

```
var player = new Object();
player.attempts = attempts;
player.completions = completions;
player.percentage = function() {
  var e = ((player.completions / player.attempts * 100);
  return e;
}
```

you can then call the function inside your string with `player.percentage()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Freethrow Percentage for # "+player.jerseyNumber+" is "+percentage.e+"%";`

With:

`document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Freethrow Percentage for # "+player.jerseyNumber+" is "+percentage()+"%";`